# How can I make a particular place where code can be shown

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering how I can make a particular area output some code but that code can only work in that particular area. 
I am using HTML and Javascript to do this, and have tried one thing:

```
<div id="messageboard">
  <script>
    function levelUp() {
      let playerLevel = 0;
        playerLevel++;
        console.log('You have reached level ' + playerLevel + '!');
        </script>
</div>
```

It's a bit confusing since the output console.log is part of a function and consequently I have had to put the function inside the divider as well.

If it will clear this whole thing up a bit, I will show the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let characterAnimation = "Character before mining.jpg";
      function levelUp() {
        let playerLevel = 0;
          playerLevel++;
          console.log('You have reached level ' + playerLevel + '!');

      }
      function mining() {
      const miningBlock = "Fast%20Typer/Mining%20Block.png";
}
      addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event keyCode === 13, 16, 20, 32, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 9, 57, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 107, 109, 110, 111, 186, 187, 188, 191, 220, 222, 221, 189) {
          levelUp();
          characterAnimation = "Character while mining";
        }
      })
      characterAnimation = "Character before mining.jpg";
</script>
<div id="messageboard">
  <script>
    function levelUp() {
      let playerLevel = 0;
        playerLevel++;
        console.log('You have reached level ' + playerLevel + '!');
        </script>
</canvas>
```

And since it all has to run, I have to put it into the same code block but then I also have to put the levelUp function into the div so that it console.logs in the correct area.
Any help would be welcome.

:)

Comment: console.log will log to the console, not to the div element.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I'm basically a noob to coding. I kind of thought that it would print to the UI, I guess.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the markup is completely invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way would be by using the alert API :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

This way you can display a message to the user.

Comment: Thanks. before you asked the question, I had made a div in the HTML and just left it like that.
That really helped.
:)